# Is it possible to obtain the network size of all loaded resources in a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, performance-testing

In order to analyse page load performance I need to know the total network size of all the resources on a page (html, static content). Is there a way to do this on the client side with javascript?

Clarification:
The data needs to be sent to a server for analysis, so I need access to network size in javascript.

Comment: The development tools of almost all modern browsers include something like this. Have you looked at one?

Comment: @Abhishek you're assuming the OP is using a browser which supports Firebug.

Comment: For example on chrome press F12, developer tool will be opened. And then click network tab, it shows some reference for you.

Comment: The data needs to be sent to a server for analysis, so I need access to such data in javascript. I'll update the question.

Comment: How about listening to XMLHttpRequests and updating a size counter on each?

Answer (score 1):

There is ongoing effort called Navigation Timing to profide such a thing:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/

The article explains how modern browsers are implementing an API to better access performance information. The most interesting part is about the processing model, you can also read about it on the w3 site:

http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#processing-model

According to the article the simplest way to try out the API is
to take a look at `window.performance` in your browser's JavaScript console.

Comment: You should probably add some relevant quotes from that article. Otherwise this is more of a comment than an answer. Link-only answers are usually frowned upon.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly At first it was a comment but I was planning to write more.

Comment: Thanks, Christophe, very interesting. This API lets you monitor timings more accurately, but doesn't seem to provide information about the network traffic generated by site's resources.

Comment: Another good read on the subject:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2013/12/12/understanding-the-real-world-performance-of-your-web-application-across-ie11-and-other-browsers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use firebug??
Check this  http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/page-load-analysis-using-firebug/

Comment: What if the user wants to test out performance on IE7 Mobile. How will Firebug help in this situation? You can't just assume someone is using a browser or even an OS which will support Firebug.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666449/javascript-code-performance-analysis-tool

Comment: @Abhishek this is from 2010.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy What makes in difference when it is working,be it in 2010 or 2050.And its been updated regularly if by chance you get a reading of it.See the documentation.

Comment: I updated the question. Firebug is good for debugging, but I need the data for future statistic analysis.